# R snow clusterCall to resource code files

Tags: r, snow

I need to call source on a `snow` cluster to re-eval some functions. The call to `clusterCall()` I'm using doesn't work:

```
cl = makeSOCKcluster(rep("localhost", 5))
> clusterCall(cl, getwd)
[[1]]
[1] "/home/user"

[[2]]
[1] "/home/user"

[[3]]
[1] "/home/user"

[[4]]
[1] "/home/user"

[[5]]
[1] "/home/user"

> clusterCall(cl, source, 'ets.load.R')
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) : 
  5 nodes produced errors; first error: cannot open the connection
```

Comment: It seems that you need to specify that 'ets.load.R' is a `file` parameter in `source` function. For example (this is not a good approach, I guess) call `clusterCall(cl, function(x) source(file=x), 'ets.load.R')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem, had to set the correct working directory first, or specify ets.load.R with its absolute path:

```
clusterEvalQ(cl, source('~/home/user/ets.load.R'))
clusterCall(cl, function() { source('~/home/users/ets.load.R'); NULL })
```